# How can I run USB to every room in the house?

Tags: wiring, walls, cabling

I want to run USB to every room in the house. I saw [USB wall sockets](https://www.electricalsupplies.co.uk/bg-nexus-metal-2-gang-socket-2-usb-sockets-brushed-steel-white-insert) on the [internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet). Is it possible (using multiple Raspberry PI or some sort of extenders) to have USB in every room?

I'm thinking I could run some sort of connected bus using Rasberry PI as extenders - USB devices -> Rasberry PI -> USB -> Rasberry PI -> USB devices. Or is it better to use Power over Ethernet ? I really don't want to have to run an IP stack and deal with all that complexity of security etc.

Comment: The linked wall sockets seem to be AC to USB power converters.  Can they also act to interconnect devices?

Comment: I haven't had a great experience with USB extenders I've seen, but it's not clear why you want USB in every room, I wouldn't count on it being more secure than Ethernet. As the previous comment says, the USB sockets you linked to are for power only, no data.

Comment: Yes you can build a pi based usb network. But you really do not want to do it. The  system you have in mind is already outdated ... twice. I do not know how USB works on the pi 2, released last month, or the B+. I know the B pi, so I will use it to give you an idea of how twisted the USB path gets. The B has 2 USB-2 ports. The ports are driven by a communication chip on the board, a LAN9512. This is the input chip for both the USB-2 and the ethernet. The LAN9512 communicates with the Processor using USB. The Processor, a BCM2835 drives its USB bus with software based. USB is not the answer.

Comment: Explain what you are attempting to achieve by doing that.

Comment: It sounds like you're **way** over complicating something, by applying the incorrect (outdated?) technology. If you tell us what you're ultimately trying to accomplish, folks might be able to give you better suggestions for how to accomplish your goal.

Comment: The complexity of custom code running on kit hardware to hack a protocol that's not designed for networking or distance work  to network your house is going to *far exceed* the complexity of running an "IP stack" (which consists of .. plugging in a $50 router).

Comment: You commented you want "cameras, sensors, and light controllers". Unfortunately there is no one unified system to do this today. IP Cameras are widely available, as are lighting systems (search for: Z-wave, Insteon or Zigbee). "Sensors" is a bit open-ended, but there is lots of off-the-shelf gear for monitoring server rooms, for example. A RaspberryPi or Ardunio is also a good solution to interfacing with random sensors, and both can be connected back to ethernet or wifi.

Comment: If you are concerned about network security, avoid any products with "cloud" features/connectivity (or be sure to turn it off). For the most part, if you don't open firewall ports on your router, and you don't have equipment making outbound connections on its own (to a "cloud" system), there's not a lot to worry about. You can also just not connect it to the internet. Don't forget about local access: either by wifi or by some random person plugging in (though this is mostly a concern in offices where there are often active, unsecured ethernet ports in reception or meeting rooms).

Comment: Thank you gregmac. Yes the plan is to fit some cool stuff (tiles that light up underfoot in the entry hall). But also, because this is council estate, get some nice security going, perhaps in tandem with a remotely monitored security company.

Comment: And also, yes, it would be nice if the system wasn't trivial to get owned.

Answer (score 3):

To get reliable USB over more than about 15 feet you'll have to use active extenders. I see a 31 foot active USB extension cable online for $15 right now. Good luck pulling the fat end through your walls, though. And it's only USB 2.0.

What are you going to do when all your old in-wall USB cables are obsolete and none of your new devices want to work with them?

These days you can transmit just about everything over Cat5e or Cat6 using converters, or convert it and transmit it over Ethernet.

Personally, I'd pull 2 or 3 Cat5e or Cat6 cables everywhere instead.

Here's just one example of allowing USB communications over an Ethernet network:  http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/USB-PS2/4-Port-USB-over-IP-Network-Hub-Adapter-USB-Ethernet-Device-Server~USB4000IP

Comment: Thanks for the comments, to answer your question, the space is a temporary space and gets pulled down in two years time.

Answer (score 1):

Some confusion in the comments - this is USB in every room.

It sounds like you may want a Pi in every room

---

The System I show works like this:

[USB 3.0]   [USB 3.0]   [USB3.0]

```
|       |     /
```

Ethernet - Ethernet - Ethernet - [USB 3.0]

```
|       |
```

[USB 3.0]  [USB 3.0]

USB 3.0 in 6 places

---

If you only want USB 2.0, the adapters are only $8

If you are really trying to build and evil (or good) Pi empire, just add a Pi where you want and you can have

USB Cam - Pi - USB - Ethernet - Ethernet - Computer

---

My suggestion was just adding the ethernet backbone:

The ethernet parts prices were to show how cheap it is to wire that way, not to avoid USB

The charging receptacles do not, can not and will not ever have data in them.

You can not have mains in the same box as low voltage data, any time you see it done, there is a separate inside the box.

You can buy these separators, so the mains and USB will share a faceplate, but inside, that is just not what is happening.

To get a roll of USB cable, without ends, you will need to order from china - try alibaba.com, it is not inexpensive.

But, however you wish, your circuit will work - the cost will shock you, you will have impressive reliability errors, adding connectors onto cable yourself will need soldering and not a crimp tool.

Just  trying to help - best of luck

---

For $20 you can get a USB 3.0 to Gigabit ethernet adapter

[http://www.amazon.com/Cable-Matters-SuperSpeed-Gigabit-Ethernet/dp/B00BBD7NFU/ref=lp_13983791_1_6?s=pc&ie=UTF8&qid=1427678239&sr=1-6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BBD7NFU)

Faster USB than the Pi, less expensive than the Pi, no need for an external power supply as the Pi would need.

Cat 6 cable is 7 cents a foot, the keystone less than $1.50, wall plate under $1, 10' 5e jumper less than $1.50

24 port Gigabit switch is less than $100.00

Run a cable from each room to a single point - fast, easy, cheap

Ethernet really is the way to go.

You do not want USB, really. The last USB standard was 3.1. The Pi B only supports 2.0, and has some comparably problems with 3.0, especially with hubs.

USB is just the wrong tool for the job. Don't force a screwdriver to do the work of a drill.

If ethernet security is an issue, run a new, wire only network. If you do not tie it into your current system, it will be about as safe as you can get.

Comment: It should be pointed out that USB is not even a networking tech.

Comment: I don't think this suggestion is what he's looking for -- I don't think he's looking for a way to provide Ethernet connectivity over USB, I think he wants to extend USB so he can plug USB devices in any room (perhaps a camera or other storage device?). Your solution would just provide ethernet, which as you point out, is better done by running ethernet cables..

Comment: That's right, I want cameras, sensors, and light controllers throughout the house, running on a USB bus. The poster's reply was great by the way. Will read the rest of the responses now.

Comment: @bryanhunt then you can  have the usb plug into the Rasberry and use the ethernet (or wireless) to connect the Rasberries to a central server

Comment: @ratchetfreak , yes - what you said. The only reason I did not mention it, was that he said he did not want to maintain a TCP/IP stack and fiddly bits. I was trying to promote that using ethernet backbone will deal with the TP/IP on its own, no help required on his part.

Comment: thanks for the great info. I can't upvote you because I don't have reputation yet but will do so once I've got some.

Comment: @SomeGuy the adapter you listed is literally an Ethernet adapter that happens to interface with a computer using USB. [One like this](http://www.startech.com/Networking-IO/USB-PS2/4-Port-USB-over-IP-Network-Hub-Adapter-USB-Ethernet-Device-Server~USB4000IP), on the other hand, literally uses Ethernet as the medium for USB communication, so you can plug USB devices into one of these and access them from elsewhere on the network as if they were directly connected with a USB cable.

Comment: @SomeGuy having said that, I agree in principle with using Ethernet instead of USB. I would add that I would also use an economical VLAN-capable router and segregate my network of "things" from my network of important computing resources to reduce the attack surface and thus mitigate the risk of getting owned.